# How to get rid of spaces on mobile version

Tags: html, css

Currently in my style.css file I am using certain designs only for the mobile version of my website.

Here is the beginning tag:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px)
```

I want to be able to set it up so that when the site is on a mobile device it does not use the &nbsp that is shown below, I want to only use `&nbsp` in the full desktop. Is there a way to handle this in a css file?

```
<td colspan="2" style="font-size: 16pt;">
 <a href="index.php">Home</a> &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; 
 <a href="product_list.php">All Products</a>
</td>
```

Comment: use margin or padding instead of `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use CSS for that. Then on the desktop site you would have to write the HTML as this

```
<td colspan="2" style="font-size: 16pt;">
 <a href="index.php">Home</a>
 <a href="product_list.php" style="margin-left: 10px;">All Products</a>
</td>
```

`&nbsp;` cannot be removed dynamically using CSS. JavaScript can handle these events, but CSS is not designed to handle this.

This way you can control the space between the elements using CSS. Now in the media style, you can remove this margin.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 150px) and (max-width : 780px) {
   td a:nth-child(2) {
      /* second a */
      margin-left: 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! I will accept your answer when I can

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two possible solutions:

1. Use margins instead of `&nbsp;` since the non-breaking space is protected and cannot be removed via CSS. You could apply `margin:0 3%;` or something alike to the anchors.
2. Wrap that `&nbsp;`s by a span: `<span class="spacer">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>` and apply `display:none` when on mobile.